# Graphic Design in Flash Pro CS5.5 Some Images don't publish correctly

Tags: flash, graphics, flash-cs5, flash-cs5.5

I am using Flash Professional CS5.5 to make a design for a poster. I basically drew these little cards as a border. Inside of Flash I have everything laid out perfectly, and it looks fine. However, when I hit export as image or publish as image some of the suit symbols for the cards don't come out right. They either don't come out at all leaving the card blank or a black rectangle fills in their image.

I want to make each suit a movieclip so it is easier to make changes later, but it is best for this purpose to use movieclip or graphic?

This is a screenshot of the exported image opened up in preview. For most of the poster, it looks fine. It is also weird because some of the spades show up and some turn out bad. It is not like one suit is the problem suit. :/

[image: http://gamesfromjames.weebly.com/uploads/1/4/1/5/14151840/607005_orig.jpg]

@dene - I took away all of the images behind the suits and htey are still not showing up right in the image file.

@mori57 - One reason is that I don't have Ilustrator. I am mainly using flash for making games, apps, and animations. However, I thought it would be cool to design a poster and have it printed. I could do everything I needed in flash, so why use Illustrator?

Thanks do you have any idea what the problem might be? Could it be that there are too many images on the stage and flash cant handle them all? I thought flash would be capable of more complex things.

Comment: Added image for you, you can remove it from your website now :)

Comment: I've experienced this glitch before too. I believe it was when I had PNG images with transparent backgrounds overlaying other PNGs. Try removing images behind the suit images (the card image, the blue background). Do the suit images appear properly then? If you can't isolate the problem, break apart the suit images.

Comment: It could also be issues with the glyphs not being included in the PDF, or printing on a frame before all the clips have been fully added to the stage... there are any number of reasons Flash could be screwing this up. ... On an aside, why are you using Flash instead of Illustrator for this? Illustrator is kind of made for print media output... Flash, not so much...

Comment: Are the suit images text symbols?

Comment: the numbers or letters in the case of a face cad or ace are tfl text because that was easier to line up on the stage. The suit images are just symbols with one image inside of them.

Comment: Maybe the FLA is corrupt. Try creating a new FLA file and placing in only the above graphics.